# Navigating inside a sheet with height animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to navigate inside a sheet view and animate its height to adapt to the new sheet height?

Basically what I am looking for is this effect:

https://i.ibb.co/hWH4gnJ/RPReplay-Final1667845678-MP4.gif

Not sure if this is possible without creating a custom view, and just using the native sheet component from SwiftUI.

I've tried different approaches and I can't get it to work. If I use `isPresented`, the view reloads and the sheet panel pops up or down to the new height without any animation. If I use `item` the panel gets dismissed and then reopens again with the new height.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 16 brings the option to use `.presentationDetents()` method that takes desired sheet height as an argument. Try assigning the method to each of your views and then change the height accordingly.

```
...
    // First view
    Text("Detail")
        .presentationDetents([.height(250)])

    // Second view
    Text("More detail")
        .presentationDetents([.height(100)])
...
```

[This](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-bottom-sheet/) site does a really good job explaining the whole process. Haven't tried that myself, but I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this solution works. I've been using `.presentationDetents()` already, and it can accept different heights to animate a single view. But it won't work in conjunction with the navigation. The sheet keeps being dismissed and then re-drawn with the new height.

Comment: Weird. When I needed to do a sheet like that, I made my own. It's basically just a rectangle with drag gesture on top, so you could always try that. If you want the code, let me know, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I was interested if there was a native way of doing it, mainly because I didn't want to handle all the user interactions and animations, for example: dimming the background, tapping outside of the panel, the small spring animation when dragging the panel up, the drag indicator...

If by any chance you have an example that I could take a look at, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: This may come around as stupid, but do you have the height change wrapped in `withAnimation{}`?  This could be causing the unwanted behavior. I'm not aware of a different way to do this natively, so I'm trying to elaborate a little bit more on the answer's solution.

Comment: I've tried both things, with and without the `withAnimation()`. And nothing seems to make the trick. 

(Worth noting that I'm a beginner in SwitUI, and I might be doing something wrong)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's gonna be something really random. As I said, I'd recommend using your own sheet, seems like the best solution in this case. Here's a nice video about it: https://youtu.be/ry1idHSmQSc